# Powershell How to use test-path knowing only a part of filename

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

can I use the classic Test-Path to check if exists into a specific folder a file with a specific word into its name?

for example, I want to check if exists a file that starts with the word "LAB". after that word there is the datestamp that I cannot calculate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why not:

```
test-path c:\myfolder\lab* -pathtype leaf #leaf is for file (get-help test-path -full)
```

Comment: how can I use it with a foreach? foreach file that starts with "lab*" echo true. I've problems with the comparison of strings.

Comment: @rschirin Post a new question with all details and code that give you error. Thanks!

Comment: is is possible to use test-path with a url. Basically I want to check if a file exists iin an http resource

Answer (score 4):

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'LAB*'
if ($files) {
   Write-Host "Found one."
}
else {
   Write-Host "Not there."
}
```

This relies on the fact that `Get-ChildItem` returns a list of the matching files. That list can then be evaluated for "truthiness".